# How do I remove a wine program?

Tags: 11.04, wine

I want to remove Spotify version 0.61 because it crashes on start up. But when I hit the "remove/modify" button it deselects my selection (spotify) and chooses the program above it (Counter-strike 1.6). I have tried to remove counter strike, BUT it gives me an error with a missing file.

So I'm stuck and I have no idea how to move on please help me.

The normal way to remove wine software doesn't work as I have said. This is how-to:

**Wine --> uninstall wine software --> select program --> remove/modify button.**

wine's uninstall program can't open the "uninstall.ini" file (counter strike 1.6)

Comment: This wine wiki FAQ link gives a good overview on [How do I uninstall...](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-ddc6f242056eb1a4fe566c9434windd15fd8b64606aa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wine is still not very good at removing programs, so your options may be rather slim. This is actually a problem inherited from the way Windows manages installed applications, so it won't change any time soon either.

You could manually remove the program's files from your virtual "C:\" Drive, then open the uninstall center and remove that application from the list. However, it is possible that the program will leave some cruft behind.

My best suggestion is that you use something like PlayOnLinux or WBM (Wine Bottle Manager) to manage your WINE applications. Even if there is not a script in PlayOnLinux for your application, you can still install it to a separate WINE prefix, and make uninstalls easier.

If you don't have too much to lose, you can go right ahead and remove your `~/.wine` folder (run `rm -r ~/.wine`) (backup first just in case), then reinstall the applications you need. Chances are, it may even fix your Spotify problems.

Comment: could you give me a command on how to remove the wine folder?

Comment: is there a way to just remove the program folder for wine, and then just reinstall wine? the first way did nothing....

Comment: @Alvar: You just remove `~/.wine` and then when you run another windows program or `winecfg` a new ~/.wine directory will be created. No need to reinstall wine.

Comment: But all my programs and all the other stuff is still here. (I ran `sudo rm -r ~/.wine`

Comment: http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-9893ae50079ca7a959258f0bc9a17aaf2e69b391
this worked. (I removed the program list in the applications menu...)

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal:

```
cd ~/.wine
```

then

```
cd /dosdevices/c:Games/
```

and remove files:

```
sudo rm -R Counter-Strike/
```